# Assets error when uploading to new directory

Tags: assets

We seem to be having an issue with P&T Assets 2.0.5 when uploading a file to a freshly created sub-folder. If I create a sub-folder and try uploading a file into it, I receive the following javascript error"

```
There was an error uploading your file: Assets could not complete the requested operation.
```

However, if we create a sub-folder, navigate to a different part of the control panel and then navigate back to Assets, we can upload to it successfully.

Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

Hope someone can help?

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1):

GazCrane -

There are a few things to check here:

1. Permissions on /system/expressionengine/cache and its subfolders need to be 777 permissions.
2. Permissions and owners on your image folders and subfolders need to also be 777 with the write ownership for uploading.

Also, are you creating these folders via Assets? Or via the filesystem?

Also, hat version of EE?  And where, exactly, are you seeing this?  Via the publish page and an Assets custom field? Via the Assets module page? That info would help!

Let me know if fixing up permissions helps!

Comment: Hey Lisa 
We're actually running into this problem on a Windows server, so the file permissions shouldn't be an issue? We're running EE2.5.5 with Assets 2.0.5. The issue is happening within the 'Assets' module page. Right-clicking on a folder and selecting 'Create Sub-Folder', then trying to upload a file to the new sub-folder.

Comment: FYI, we had some [indexing problems last week](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/not_indexing_correctly?utm_content=topic_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification). Could these two problems be related in any way?

Comment: They absolutely could be, and unfortunately, Windows servers are actually more problematic with permissions.  Are you running Apache or IIS?  And do you have a sysadmin that can look at permissions for you?

Comment: We're running IIS. I'll take a look at the file permissions for the existing and 'new' sub-folders to see if I can see any patterns. Back soon.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything strange or different between the my upload folder and any other folder within my site. All are set to allow IIS (IIS_IUSRS) to read, write, list and execute. Seems strange that uploading fails upon creation of a new sub-folder but works fine if we navigate away from the Assets page then go back? Thanks for helping me with this one Lisa :-)

Comment: My pleasure, GazCrane!  Is it possible to get direct access to your site? FTP and Super Admin access would be preferable.  If so, please email those (and a link to this thread) to support@pixelandtonic.com.  Thank you!